# How to select random rows for each user in a table; and if possible for each day

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set, which is extracted from a server that contains various columns of which one column has the UserID; this data will be dumped in an Excel sheet.

My task is to select one row for each user randomly and paste it in another sheet.

My sample data will be as below:

[image]

I am trying to accomplish this by extracting the random values.

However, its giving me error. Could you please help me.Thanks

My code (not complete):

```
Sub randomsmpl()
Dim data(), dict As Object, r As Long
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

data = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Value

For r = 1 To UBound(data)
    dict(data(r, 7)) = Empty
Next

data = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dict.keys())

End Sub
```

This code was taken from the internet and modified a bit.

I am getting error "Subscript out of Range" for the row:
`dict(data(r, 7)) = Empty`

Please let me know if there is any other way to complete this task.

Thanks

Comment: Please include the name/number of the error and on which line it occurs in your question.

Comment: how is dating getting into sheet?

Comment: `data = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Value` To do this, you must define `data` as Variant, `Dim data as Variant` but you are doing `Dim data()`

Comment: Values in your `Column(1)`, are they unique?

Comment: @Foxfire, I tried making it as variant, but still getting the same error

Comment: @Zac, Yes its unique in Column1; but the last column "User ID" is not unique, as the same user can attend multiple Ref numbers. Hence I need to get one Ref number for each User ID randomly. Thanks

Comment: You are taking 1 single column into an array, so `data(r, 7)` makes no sense (it would if you where taking 7 columns). It should be `data(r, 1)`.

Comment: Not completely sure what you are trying to achieve but your array only has 1 column and you are trying to reference column 7.. which is what throws the error

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns great minds and all of that :)

Comment: **Hints**: add `data` as a watch and then have a look at it in **Watch** window after you have assigned it a value. Also it is highly recomended that you dont use reserved words as your variable name (i.e. **`data`**)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. I have changed the column number to 7 in 4th line as I need to get rows based on that. and inside For loop I have made it (r,1). When I run this, it seems like running but unable to paste the data in a different sheet...